# can I change how do I see the results of a find in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We all know the find and replace function (ctrl-f)
Well in excel once you use this, and if you find what you are looking, the results are hardly noticeable. I have to see which column has a darker shade and which row has a darker shade and that is how I find it.

Is there a way that I can see the results highlighted somehow so there are easier to see?

Answer (score 1):

If you find that the selected cell in search is not very "findable" you probably have formatted the cells with a heavy, dark border. You may find that the selected cell is much easier to see if there is no border, or at least not a thick, dark one.

[image]
[image]